# Can the spell Floating Disk cut objects?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, targeting, objects

Can the spell [*floating disk*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/floating-disk) cut objects?

The text of the spell doesn't give any restriction on where you can summon the disk, so could you summon it halfway through a lock or door to gain entry?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Fortunately or unfortunately, line of effect prohibits creating a disk in such a space

The spell [*floating disk*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/floating-disk) has the entry ***Effect*** 3-ft.-diameter disk of force, making it an effect spell, and [Aiming a Spell](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/#TOC-Aiming-a-Spell) on Line of Effect, in part, says, "You must have a clear line of effect… to any space in which you wish to create an effect."

Thus in the same way a [*summon monster*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/summon-monster/) spell can't explode a foe by conjuring a creature within that foe, a floating disk can't be created so that it shatters a door or lock.

Comment: What about a transparent door? :-P

Comment: @JoshuaD Although I have been `:-P`ed, that's actually a thing: there's a difference between line of sight and line of effect—for example, utter darkness blocks line of sight but not line of effect, and a transparent door blocks line of effect but not line of sight.